# Dynamically Displaying Image using Javascript to Laravel Blade template

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Good day! So I have been practising web development again and found Laravel to be fun to learn (and I'm enjoying it a lot) and I have decided to recreate my portfolio website with it to practice it.

So the problem is this:
I am trying to display a list of images from a folder called `designImages` and this will be updated every time I have a good UI design. so it makes sense to make it **dynamically ready** so I do not have to manually add `<img>` tags for every image and make my process a lot longer. I plan to just make a js file that will only be adjusted once depending on how many images are currently in the folder.

But the problem is when I display the images on my blade page, it shows the broken image icon
[view it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFHec.png)

EDIT: When I try to inspect element, the image is not displaying and instead, shows 404 error. mywebsite.test/designImages/design-1 for example.

The code on my **js file** is this

const imageContainer = document.querySelector(".imageContainer");

```
for (let i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
    const img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "{{ asset('designImages/design-${i}.png') }}";
    imageContainer.append(img);
}
```

and the code for the **master file** (`app.blade.php`) for my `index.blade.php` is:

```
<body>
    @yield('content-5')
    @stack('head')
</body>
```

and the **index.blade.php** code is this:

```
@section('content-5')
    <div class="imageContainer">
        <!-- images will come here -->
    </div>
@endsection

@push('head')
    <script src="{{ asset('js/imageGrid.js')}}"></script>
@endpush
```

Any help or tips will be greatly appreciated :)

-----EDIT-----

Fixed it! :) the updated javascript code is this:

```
const templateURL = "storage/designImages/design-?.png";
const imageContainer = document.querySelector(".imageContainer");

for (let i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
    const img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = templateURL.replace("?", i);
    imageContainer.append(img);
}
```

Comment: `designImages/design-1` or `designImages/design-1.png`? Does the file exist in the `public/designImages` folder?

Comment: Hi @bombeer

Yes

Comment: fixed it

const templateURL = "storage/designImages/design-?.png";
const imageContainer = document.querySelector(".imageContainer");

for (let i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
    const img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = templateURL.replace("?", i);
    imageContainer.append(img);
}

Comment: Though I don't know why I have to hardcode the storage/ one in the javascript or I think its because it's javascript and is an external file not js code inside the blade?

if you or anyone can explain, it'll be better so I can learn more :)

Answer (score 0):

fixed it using this code:

```
const templateURL = "storage/designImages/design-?.png";
const imageContainer = document.querySelector(".imageContainer");

for (let i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
    const img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = templateURL.replace("?", i);
    imageContainer.append(img);
}
```